# Python - Make if statement in while loops restart the loop, not the condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code that is supposed to determine the volume of a shape, determined by input. I have several if statements nested in a while loop. I want the loop to restart at the very beginning where it asks for input, but instead it is getting stuck in the condition statement. For example, if I enter "cube", it computes the volume and then asks me again to input the dimensions - instead I want it to ask me the shape, and proceed through the if statements again. Same at the end, if I enter a shape that isn't valid, it's supposed to ask me to input again and if that input is valid, proceed accordingly. But it doesn't, it gets stuck in an infinite loop and never stops asking me to input a shape.

```
import math
import decimal

shape = str(input("Please enter a shape: "))
shape = shape.lower()

shapes = ["cube", "pyramid", "ellipsoid", "quit"]

stored_cube_vol = []
stored_pymd_vol = []
stored_ellip_vol = []

while shape != "quit":
    if shape == "cube":
        def cube_volume(cube_side_length):
            cube_total_vol = decimal.Decimal(cube_side_length**3)
            return round(cube_total_vol, 2)

        cube_side_length = float(input("Enter the length of length of one side of the cube: "))

        print("The volume of a cube with sides with a length of", cube_side_length, "is", cube_volume(cube_side_length))

        stored_cube_vol.append(cube_volume(cube_side_length))

    elif shape == "pyramid":
        def pymd_volume(pymd_base, pymd_height):
            pymd_total_vol = decimal.Decimal(pymd_base**2)*pymd_height*(1/3)
            return round(pymd_total_vol, 2)

        pymd_base = float(input("Enter the length of the base of the pyramid: "))
        pymd_height = float(input("Enter the height of the pyramid: "))

        print("The volume of a pyramid with a base of", pymd_base, "and a height of", pymd_height, "is", pymd_volume(pymd_base, pymd_height))

        stored_pymd_vol.append(pymd_volume(pymd_base, pymd_height))

    elif shape == "ellipsoid":
        def ellip_volume(ellip_rad_1, ellip_rad_2, ellip_rad_3):
            ellip_total_vol = decimal.Decimal(math.pi*(4/3)*ellip_rad_1*ellip_rad_2*ellip_rad_3)
            return round(ellip_total_vol, 2)

        ellip_rad_1 = float(input("Enter the first radius: "))
        ellip_rad_2 = float(input("Enter the second radius: "))
        ellip_rad_3 = float(input("Enter the third radius: "))

        print("The volume of an ellipsoid with radii", ellip_rad_1, ellip_rad_2, "and", ellip_rad_3, "is", ellip_volume(ellip_rad_1, ellip_rad_2, ellip_rad_3))

        stored_ellip_vol.append(ellip_volume(ellip_rad_1, ellip_rad_2, ellip_rad_3))

    elif shape == "quit":
        print("You have come to the end of the session.")
        print("The volumes calculated for each shape are shown below.")
        print("Cube: ", sorted(stored_cube_vol))
        print("Pyramid: ", sorted(stored_pymd_vol))
        print("Ellipsoid: ", sorted(stored_ellip_vol))

    else:
        str(input("Please enter a shape: ").lower())
```

Comment: Why are you defining functions inside of your loop?

Comment: because I don't know what I'm doing lol.. can i put all of those before the while loop begins?

Comment: You want to call shape = input... at the start of the while loop. At the moment after the cube calculation, the shape =cube still so it goes back inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `shape =` in your `else` clause.

If I understand correctly, just **remove** the `else` clause and leave:

```
shape = str(input("Please enter a shape: ")).lower()
```

at the end of the loop.

This will ask the user as long as he didn't enter `"quit"`, even if he did enter a valid choice.

Comment: this worked thank you! but now i have the problem that when i enter quit, it doesn't print what it's supposed to, the process just ends..

Comment: you could change your while condition to simply 'while True', then add a break at the end of your quit condition

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to the code. I have put the statements taking input from the user into the while loop and added a break statement in the 'if=='quit'' statement.

Change 1:

```
import math
import decimal

shapes = ["cube", "pyramid", "ellipsoid", "quit"]

stored_cube_vol = []
stored_pymd_vol = []
stored_ellip_vol = []
shape = " "
while shape != "quit":
    shape = str(input("Please enter a shape: "))
    shape = shape.lower()
```

Change 2:

```
elif shape == "quit":
    print("You have come to the end of the session.")
    print("The volumes calculated for each shape are shown below.")
    print("Cube: ", sorted(stored_cube_vol))
    print("Pyramid: ", sorted(stored_pymd_vol))
    print("Ellipsoid: ", sorted(stored_ellip_vol))
    break
```